# Remove all annotations in Java source code and get new source code

Tags: java, annotations

I am looking for ways to remove all the annotations from existing Java Source Code. I am looking for an ant task or any other approach. I have seen some solutions that do this at the class level, but I am looking to do this at the source code to source code level.

Comment: You could probably use some kind of script - try `grep -v` or some clever `sed`, but it would help to know what you are trying to achieve, because annotations are used for a lot of different things today, and to remove them all indiscriminately is potentially a bad idea...

Comment: I am looking to use annotations for server side, but same code, we need to use on device side, some devices such as JavaME does not support annotations. Hence, at build time. I could do search and replace.. but I am looking for engineering solution so that, mistakes can be less in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this through Java Parser code available in Lombok.

Look at these methods which has the logic

lombok.javac.handlers.JavacHandlerUtil#deleteAnnotationIfNecessary
lombok.javac.handlers.JavacHandlerUtil#deleteImportFromCompilationUnit

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) which has brilliant [regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) support.

I wanted to replace specific annotations (I wanted to keep stuff like `@Override`). You can easily do that for all buffers or a directory tree.

Just write some simple expressions for the annotations you want to remove. For example

```
^\s*@NamedQueries\(\n\{[^\}]+\}\)\n
```